# How do I SELECT all values NOT related to a record

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Table1 = **Users** (fields: id,username)

Table2 = **Groups** (fields: id,groupname)

*(users can be assigned to multiple groups via table3)*

Table3 = **usr_grp** (fields: userid,groupid)

This query tells me **ALL** the groups related to the userid=1

```
SELECT g.groupname FROM groups g INNER JOIN usr_grp u ON u.groupid=g.id WHERE u.userid=1
```

What would the mysql query be to return **ALL** the groupnames the userid=1 is **NOT** assigned to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select g.groupname
from groups g
left join user_grp u on u.groupid=g.id and u.userid=1
where u.groupid is null
```

or the equivalent

```
select g.groupname
from groups g
where not exists (
    select 1 from user_grp u
    where u.userid=1 and u.groupid=g.id
)
```

or

```
select g.groupname
from groups g
where g.id not in (select groupid from usr_grp where userid=1)
```